# Temperature dependency of charge carrier mobility and resistance in MOSFETs

Tags: mosfet, propagation

I am a little bit confused about this. I used to think that in regular conductors the resistance increases with an increase in temperature because the charge carriers collide more frequently and thus the mean velocity of them decreases.

In semiconductors we learned that an increase in temperature can lead to electrons in the valence band to gain sufficient thermal energy to move into the conduction band and therefore decreasing the resistance with increasing temperature.

I was looking into the temperature dependency propagation delay of CMOS logic. I found that the delay goes up with an increase in temperature. Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The temperature dependency of the propagation delay in CMOS logic is a complex phenomenon that is influenced by a number of different factors. In general, an increase in temperature can lead to an increase in the delay of CMOS logic gates for several reasons, including the following:

1. Increased thermal noise: As the temperature increases, the thermal
   energy of the electrons in the circuit also increases, which can
   lead to an increase in the level of thermal noise. This noise can
   interfere with the signals in the circuit and cause delays in the
   propagation of the signals.
2. Reduced device performance: As the temperature increases, the
   performance of the transistors in the CMOS logic gates may decrease,
   which can lead to slower switching times and longer delays in the
   propagation of the signals.
3. Increased leakage current: As the temperature increases, the leakage
   current in the transistors may also increase, which can
   cause additional delays in the propagation of the signals.

Overall, the temperature dependency of the propagation delay in CMOS logic is a complex phenomenon that is influenced by a variety of different factors. While an increase in temperature can sometimes lead to a decrease in resistance in semiconductors, it can also have negative impacts on the performance of CMOS logic gates and lead to increased delays in the propagation of signals.

Answer (score 0):

Applying the statement about the resistance of intrinsic semiconductors to the CMOS device operation, the OP underestimates their confusion (`I am a little bit confused ...`).

The temperature dependency of the MOSFET channel resistance can be measured directly, or, the better approach, it can be derived from simulation, because the MOSFET device models are well established to correctly represent these values for a wide temperature range.

Let us simulate a 0.18um CMOS inverter, with NMOS (l=0.18u w=0.18u) and PMOS (l=0.18u w=0.45u).

The plots of drain-to-source resistance (RDSON) for both NMOS and PMOS devices have positive temperature coefficients. The resistance values grow almost linearly from 75KOhm @ 0°C to 109KOhm @125°C for NMOS and from 30KOhm @0°C to 42KOhm @125°C for PMOS.

[image: RDS-NMOS]

[image: RDS-PMOS]

This experimentally confirmed positive temperature coefficient in no way is at odds with the negative temperature coefficient of **intrinsic** semiconductors: the MOSFET channel region is anything but pure semiconductor. The body of an n-channel FET is doped with acceptor atoms, creating an p-type bulk; the body of an p-channel FET is doped with donor atoms, creating an n-type bulk.

The behavior of doped (**extrinsic**) semiconductors in the electric field is different than the behavior of intrinsic semiconductors. Let us consider the behavior of an n-type doped semiconductor.

At low temperatures, when the donor sites do not receive enough energy to migrate to the conduction band, the extrinsic semiconductor behaves similarly to the intrinsic semiconductor. As the temperature is rising, typically at 200°K, the donors become ionized, and at room temperature all the donors are ionized.

Now, the quantity of donor-generated carriers in the conduction band is independent of temperature (all the donors are ionized), but the number of "intrinsic"-generated carriers (from the valence band) is still negligible in comparison with the dopant-generated carriers: the majority carrier concentration is made up of the donor electrons, and the resistivity is fully defined by mobility. The mobility of carriers decreases with increase in temperature because of phonon scattering. The mobility in silicon semiconductor is dominated by acoustic phonon interaction, and this time it is identical behavior for both the intrinsic and extrinsic semiconductors.

As the temperature rises higher, above ~500°K, thermally generated electrons from the valence band overweigh the quantity of donor-generated electrons and the semiconductor again behaves as intrinsic.

For a p-type semiconductor (doped with acceptors) the consideration is similar, only the carriers are holes. Note that the hole mobility in silicon is also dominated by acoustic phonon interaction.